# AngularJs ng-click not working in jquery dynatable grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating an html with ng-repeat like:

```
var li = '<div ng-repeat="list in viewsList">...</div>';
```

and then using

```
 var html = angular.element(li);
 angular.element("#grid-view-list").html($compile(html)($scope));
```

to compile my code. After this I try to create jquery dynatable, in which I am pretty successful. However, all the events like ng-click etc. in my code stop working after this.
Adding [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oVNDnI5Zj1culXpvDpgJ?p=preview).

Any suggestions or help would be great contribution.

Answer (score 0):

ng-click won't work inside ng-repeat most of the times.

Because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope.

Please go through this link : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Probably conflict between scopes. Need more resources from your side to figure the issue. Any codepen/jsfiddle would be beneficial.

Comment: I have created this quick 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oVNDnI5Zj1culXpvDpgJ?p=preview)